# confirm-ack-channel is not getting invoked

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

Below is my config. In case of successful posting to queue the flow is not passing to confirm-ack-channel. Can anyone suggest where am going wrong?

```
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="fulfillmentOutboundChannel"
                                   routing-key="xyz"
                                   amqp-template="transactionalRabbitTemplate"
                                   confirm-correlation-expression="payload"
                                   confirm-ack-channel="successRespTransformChannel"
                                   confirm-nack-channel="failureRespTransformChannel"
                                   return-channel="failureRespTransformChannel"
                                   mapped-request-headers="*"


        />


<int:channel id="successRespTransformChannel">

    <int:interceptors><int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel"/></int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<chain input-channel="successRespTransformChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
    <error-channel ref="failed-publishing" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <service-activator id="successResp" expression="@abc.addRequestTracking(payload.id,'success')"/>

</chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get acks/nacks, in addition to setting up the adapter with `confirm-correlation`, You also need to enable `publisherConfirms` on the `CachingConnectionFactory`.

From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms):

> For Publisher Confirms (aka Publisher Acknowledgements), the template requires a CachingConnectionFactory that has its `publisherConfirms` property set to true.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gary.I have already made the publisg-confirms=true as below. Still the ack is not getting invoked

Comment: down vote
accept
Thanks for your response Gary. I have already made publish-confirms=true as below..

<rabbit:connection-factory id="fufillConnectionFactory"

 connection-factory="rabbitClientConnectionFactory"
                               publisher-confirms="true"
                               publisher-returns="true"/

Comment: Still its not working . My service Activator is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response Gary. I have already made publish-confirms=true as below..

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="fufillConnectionFactory"

 connection-factory="rabbitClientConnectionFactory"
                               publisher-confirms="true"
                               publisher-returns="true"/>


    <bean id="rabbitClientConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory" >
        <property name="uri" value="${mq.uri}" />
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="30" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Don't use a new answer for this, edit the question instead.